# What is the best way to get Reward Tickets?

Tags: xenoblade-chronicles-x

Reward tickets are the best end-game currency, because they can buy any monster-dropped item. Because of this, they're very useful when buying upper-tier skells such as the Ares 70, 90, and the super weapons.

What is the fastest way to get reward tickets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grind for the Phoenix/Buster weapon on site 406, kill the Puge guys. If you already have a strong weapon, ignore this. For me, I just grind the bottom right Squad tasks when they come up. After I finish those, I go to the Blade Barracks and do the squad missions, I get about 300-500 tickets each time I finish and solo them all since not a lot of people do this. When Squad missions are down, I recruit 3 level 60 Blade scouts, and go to Noctilum Site 206 and kill "The Joker." This will level the Blade scout's Blade level to MAX and once it hits max, you receive 5 tickets each, netting you 15 tickets. Just rinse and repeat this process until Squad tasks come back up.

Comment: +1 Also as a helpful tip after killing Joker you can just get out of your skell and then get use the menu option 'Return to Skell' to force a reload and respawn him instantly. This is great for leveling your classes, too! Maxing out the scout levels also nets BLADE medals, which you can use to fight the global nemesis for a lot of reward tickets.